# [Flex]Static XML files are not exported when, building the Project

Tags: xml, apache-flex, file, export

I am doing a video library. Each category has it's own XML files that feeds it data. Everything works great.

However, when I Exported the Release Build. I noticed those XML files are gone(i.e. never got exported). I don't understand why. I need the video library to be dynamic so I can add or remove videos.

Anyone know why those files are not exported along with the rest of the project. Like a setting in the preference that I need to fix??

thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming that the XML files have indeed been imported into the project, into the src directory?

Answer (score 0):

In the "Flex Compiler" section of your project's Properties, make sure "Copy Non-Embedded Files To Output Folder" is checked. I believe any files you want copied need to be in one of your source folders.